# Is this a correct answer

Tags: grammar, translation, words, reading-comprehension

I'm doing an exercise where I need to complete a sentence, I got this sentence

> 田中さんはいじわるだから、一緒に..............たくありません

is :

> 田中さんはいじわるだから、一緒にもう話したくありません

a correct answer ? I don't know if I understood the sentence correctly but does the sentence with my answer means "Because Tanaka is mean, I don't want to talk with him anymore"?
At least that's what I aimed with that answer but I'm really concerned about the use of `一緒に` in that sentence, I know that `一緒に` means "together" and is used to modify an action verb as in “do something together”, but in this sentence `一緒に..............たくありません` it's "me" who don't want to do the action with him so why using `一緒に`
if someone can make it more clear for me it would be nice.

ありがとう　:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 田中さんはいじわるだから、一緒に**もう話し**たくありません

Your answer is nearly correct, but not perfect. If the exercise were not conditional, you could say like this with the same meaning "Because Tanaka is mean, I don't want to talk with him anymore" with using the same words:

> 田中さんはいじわるだから、もう一緒に話したくありません

but, the following sentence is the correct answer:

> 田中さんはいじわるだから、一緒に**話し**たくありません

Generally the ideal answer is the answer that is shown in naruto's answer as

> 田中さんはいじわるだから、一緒に**い**たくありません

Next,

> ...but I'm really concerned about the use of 一緒に in that sentence, I know that 一緒に means "together" and is used to modify an action verb as in “do something together”, but in this sentence 一緒に..............たくありません it's "me" who don't want to do the action with him so why using 一緒に...

The sentence of the exercise

> 田中さんはいじわるだから、一緒に..............たくありません

is the short form of

> 田中さんはいじわるだから、**私は田中さんと**一緒に..............たくありません

If you omit the conditional clause "田中さんはいじわるだから", it becomes as

> 私は田中さんと一緒に..............たくありません

I know you understand the meaning as

> I don't want to do something together with Tanaka.

Now I know you got it.

You can fill the blank with varous correct answers besides "話｛はな｝し" and "い", like:

> - 田中さんはいじわるだから、一緒に「遊｛あそ｝び」たくありません
> - 田中さんはいじわるだから、一緒に「泳｛およ｝ぎ」たくありません
> - 田中さんはいじわるだから、一緒に「食｛た｝べ」たくありません
> - 田中さんはいじわるだから、一緒に「遊｛あそ｝びに行｛い｝き」たくありません
> - 田中さんはいじわるだから、一緒に「泳｛およ｝ぎに行｛い｝き」たくありません
> - 田中さんはいじわるだから、一緒に「食｛た｝べに行｛い｝き」たくありません

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if two people try to talk to you simultaneously, that's 一緒に話す.

[image]

But if there are only two people chatting, that's also 一緒に話す, although 一緒に is redundant.

[image]

So your sentence feels a bit redundant but is not wrong. If you can choose an arbitrary verb, how about 一緒にいたくありません?